# Elements go outside their parent container

Tags: html, css

I have an issue that I'm running into. I'm using the grid.css file. The classes that are not mentioned are empty.

So the problem is that when there are 3 columns with images that (in pixels) are realy big in the MAIN ARTICLE AREA. They go over the size of the container. And into the SIDEBAR area. How could I fix this issue?

I hope I'm clear enough, if not let me know, I fill fix it. :)

**EDIT** I figured out the issue. I had to add this to the css and now the images don't go over their size.

```
.related articles img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

With this it works fine.

```
<section class="article">
    <div class="row">
         <!--MAIN ARTICLE AREA-->
        <div class="col span-2-of-3 col-left">
            <div class="related-articles">
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/test_img.jpg" alt="test-img">
                        <h3>This is a test article, I'm just trying out new things and lets see how this goes.</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>

                 <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/test_img.jpg" alt="test-img">
                        <h3>This is a test article, I'm just trying out new things and lets see how this goes.</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>

                 <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/test_img.jpg" alt="test-img">
                        <h3>This is a test article, I'm just trying out new things and lets see how this goes.</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--SIDEBAR STARTS-->
        <div class="col span-1-of-3 col-right">

        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

And the CSS

```
.row{
max-width: 1140px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.article .col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0.5% 0 0.5% 0;
}

.span-2-of-3 {
    width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-1-of-3 {
    width: 32.26%; 
}

.col-left{
    border-top: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    float: left;
}

.col-right{
    float: right;
/*THE HEIGHT AND COLOR IS JUST SO I KNOW HOW IT WILL LOOK*/
    height:800px; 
    color:aqua;
}
```

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Although people have made decent guesses as to what your issue is, you don't make it very clear what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 1):

**JSfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ua7o3pf9/

**Corrected Code:**

```
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;
}

.span-2-of-3 {
    width: 64.6%; 
}

.span-1-of-3 {
    width: 31.6%; 
}
```

You calculated your widths and margins false. Fixed it for you. It must be 100% or below in total.

**Edit:**

Also fixed sidebar color for you: https://jsfiddle.net/ua7o3pf9/1/

**Edit 2: Fixed Code for your edited question:**

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ua7o3pf9/9/

Code:

```
<div class="related-articles article">
```

You forgot to add the class `article`, this is why the `float:left` wasnt added to your cols.

Comment: I made a mistake showing you the CSS, check it out, how it looks now. It doesn't go over 100%.

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/ua7o3pf9/9/ It works now. U forgot to add the article class (which adds float:left;) to the container.

Comment: @TacoCat check this one out: https://jsfiddle.net/ua7o3pf9/10/ Also fixed the broken image links for you. You have to add `width:100%` to the imgs.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.col` style to:

```
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;
}
```